# ASP.NET Core application with LDAP authentication on Docker image

Tags: c#, docker, ldap, windows-server-2016

I created a sample ASP.NET webapi application that authenticates the user in the domain through this piece of code:

```
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain"))
        {
            isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password);
        }
```

above code come from

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagment(4.5.0).dll
```

When the image is published and run on production and user sends POST request to above piece of code, an exception is thrown:

```
      Connection id "0HLERL2WAHD8H", Request id "0HLERL2WAHD8H:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the appli
cation.
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted. ---> System.
DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequestHelper(DirectoryRequest request, Int32& messageID)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties&
properties)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

My application can't achieve LDAP server, however, when I publish this application on standard IIS server, everything works as expected.

Any help will be appreciated.

dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
COPY pub/ /root/
WORKDIR /root/
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:80"
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Comment: I have updated my post, so you can follow the stack trace. Seems that the Connect() method is throwing the exception.

Comment: You have opened up the necessary ports on the Docker instance?

Comment: No I haven't. I didn't even know that I have to. I'm fairly new in docker world.
Could you point which ports should be open and how to add appropriate code in dockerfile?

Comment: Docker network configuration tasks are not on-topic on Stack Overflow. You may want to ask on Server Fault how to configure docker instead.

Comment: Found solution?